# Facebook login in C#

Tags: facebook, authentication

My problem may be simple to others. I just need a login just like
Stack Overflow.

I searched in Google I can't find at least close to my inquiry.
I use the example of Facebook here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins

but I can't move on the next which is showing the profile pic additional information etc.

Comment: All I need is a golden toilet. What is the question here?

Comment: How can I makes something like the login here in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the facebook graph : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: I got this link http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/developing-with-facebook-api-sdk-w-asp.net you got that link of yours, How can I get the profile pic and name of the user? etc.

Comment: Basically, you need to authenticate your user, either using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) or [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) From there you get an access token, which give you access to the facebook graph, fql and so on. (see link in my post). You could also use [fbml](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/fbml/) login, but it has been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre for your kind response. I used Facebook dev toolkit, and got the userinfo.